# Memory map lookup table (LUT)

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, lookup-tables

I am writting a flash driver, and I have a function that retrieves the memory sector based on the address, and another function that finds the sector size based on the sector.

How to use a lookup table instead of if conditions?

My current implementation:

```c
hal_status_t flashGetSector(uint32_t address, uint32_t* sectorResult) {
  hal_status_t status = HAL_STATUS_SUCCESS;

  /*BANK1 start*/
  if((address < 0x08003FFF) && (address >= 0x08000000)) {
    *sectorResult = FLASH_SECTOR_0;
    return status;
  }
  if((address < 0x08007FFF) && (address >= 0x08004000)) {
    *sectorResult = FLASH_SECTOR_1;
    return status;
  }

/*more sectors...*/

  if((address < 0x081FFFFF) && (address >= 0x081E0000)) {
    *sectorResult = FLASH_SECTOR_23;
    return status;
  }

  return HAL_STATUS_ILLEGAL;
}
```

```c
hal_status_t flashGetSectorSize(uint32_t sector, uint32_t* sectorSize) {
  if((sector == FLASH_SECTOR_0) || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_1) || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_2) ||  (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_3)
     || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_12) || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_13) || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_14) || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_15)) {
    *sectorSize = 16 * 1024;
    return HAL_STATUS_SUCCESS;
  }

  if((sector == FLASH_SECTOR_4) || (sector == FLASH_SECTOR_16)) {
    *sectorSize = 64 * 1024;
    return HAL_STATUS_SUCCESS;
  }

  if ((sector >= FLASH_SECTOR_5 && sector <= FLASH_SECTOR_11) || (sector >= FLASH_SECTOR_17 && sector <= FLASH_SECTOR_23) ) {
    *sectorSize = 128 * 1024;
    return HAL_STATUS_SUCCESS;
  }

  return HAL_STATUS_ILLEGAL;
}
```

Comment: It's odd that you put greater address on the left. Anyway, write a loop. Are `FLASH_SECTOR_0` equal to `0, 1, 2 ...` ?

Comment: IMHO a table is over the top.  The second block would be tidier with a switch-case, the first one is best with if-else, like you have it.  But @KamilCuk is correct that it would be easier to read with the lower limit on the left of the && and the upper limit on the right.

Comment: I wish C had `constexpr` of C++. It would be quite easy to generate LUTs during compile-time and place them on flash memory if C had them. I'm using this method in my embedded C++ projects.

Comment: BTW, which model/part is this? Some STM32F4 or STM32F7 I guess...

Comment: It's STM32F439ZI with 2MB of flash

Comment: you need also bak number for the erase operations.

Comment: Given that flash erase is going to be the massive bottleneck of this code, why does it matter if the address lookup code is somewhat inefficient? Yes it could be improved but _why_ do you need to do that? This can't be performance-critical code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along:

```
typedef uint32_t sector_t;
typedef uint32_t address_t;
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x)  sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)

static const sector_t _idx_to_sector[] = {
    FLASH_SECTOR_0,
    FLASH_SECTOR_1,
    FLASH_SECTOR_2,
    ...
};

size_t sector_to_idx(sector_t sector) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(_idx_to_sector); ++i) {
         if (_idx_to_sector[i] == sector) {
              return i;
         }
     }
     return -1;
}

#define SMALL_SECTOR_SIZE   (16 * 1024)
#define MEDIUM_SECTOR_SIZE  (64 * 1024)
static const address_t _sector_sizes[] = {
    [0] = SMALL_SECTOR_SIZE,
    [1] = SMALL_SECTOR_SIZE,
    ...
    [4] = MEDIUM_SECTOR_SIZE,
    [5] = SMALL_SECTOR_SIZE,
    [6] = MEDIUM_SECTOR_SIZE,
    ...
};

hal_status_t flashGetSectorSize(sector_t sector, address_t *sectorSize) {
      const size_t idx = sector_to_idx(sector);
      if (idx == (size_t)-1) return FAILURE;
      *sectorSize = _sector_sizes[idx];
      return SUCCESS;
}

hal_status_t flashGetSector(address_t address, sector_t *seectorResult) {
     const address_t startaddress = 0x08000000;
     if (address < startaddress) return FAILURE;
     address -= startaddress; // 0...0x1FFFFF
     for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(_idx_to_sector); ++i) {
         const address_t sectorsize = _sector_sizes[i];
         // check for each in range - move to the next
         if (address < sectorsize) {
                *seectorResult = _idx_to_sector[i];
                return SUCCESS;
         }
         address -= sectorsize;
     }
     return FAILURE;
}
```

Multiple arrays may be hard to manage - you may consider doing a struct where you keep all your "sector description" in one place.

Comment: nor good enough for this part. Bank number is also needed for erase operation